# RetryableHazelcastException when launching cluster using Hazelcast 3.7

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a cluster with two members that have map loaders to a database.

Version 3.6.1 shows no issues during startup - however when I upgraded to 3.7, I was presented with lots of exceptions like below - and the cluster failed to start!

Any ideas what it means?
Thanks

14:32:50.613), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, name=TRADE_SETTLEMENT}, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeoutMillis=60000, firstInvocationTimeMs=1473427838152, firstInvocationTime='2016-09-09 14:30:38.152', lastHeartbeatMillis=0, lastHeartbeatTime='1970-01-01 01:00:00.000', target=[xxx.co.uk]:5702, pendingResponse={VOID}, backupsAcksExpected=0, backupsAcksReceived=0, connection=null}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map TRADE_SETTLEMENT is still loading data from external store
Sep 09, 2016 2:32:50 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation